# When and why do we need ApplicationRunner and Runner interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring boot. What's some typical use cases for `ApplicationRunner` or any runner interface?

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class PersistencedemoApplicationTests implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
       // load initial data in test DB
    }
}
```

This is one case I'm aware of. Anything else?

Comment: Another case may also be related to readiness/liveness health checks. *liveness* state should only be about the internal state of the service and *readiness* should deal with anything related to "accepting traffic", so we may want to move any long-running tasks (e.g. initializing some cache, loading some additional data etc.) to `ApplicationRunner` to let Spring handle them before getting "ready". Spring docs also mention this [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-availability.readiness).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

These runners are used to run the logic on application startup, for example spring boot has [ApplicationRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html)(Functional Interface) with `run` method.

> ApplicationRunner run() will get executed, just after applicationcontext is created and before spring boot application startup.
>
> ApplicationRunner takes ApplicationArgument which has convenient methods like getOptionNames(), getOptionValues() and getSourceArgs().

And [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) is also a Functional Interface with `run` method

> CommandLineRunner run() will get executed, just after applicationcontext is created and before spring boot application starts up.
>
> It accepts the argument, which are passed at time of server startup.

Both of them provides the same functionality and the only difference between `CommandLineRunner` and `ApplicationRunner` is `CommandLineRunner.run()` accepts `String array[]` whereas `ApplicationRunner.run()` accepts `ApplicationArguments` as argument. You can find more information with example at [Guide To Running Logic on Startup in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring)

Answer (score 3):

Or like this:

```
@Bean
ApplicationRunner appStarted() {
    return args -> {
        logger.info("Ready to go - args: {}", args.getNonOptionArgs());
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you add more info to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use *ApplicationRunner* or *CommandLineRunner* interfaces, one needs to create a ***Spring bean*** and implement either *ApplicationRunner* or *CommandLineRunner* interfaces, both perform similarly. Once complete, your Spring application will detect your bean.

In addition, you can create multiple *ApplicationRunner* or *CommandLineRunner* beans, and control the ordering by implementing either

- org.springframework.core.Ordered interface
- org.springframework.core.annotation.Order annotation.

**use case:**

1. One might wish to log some command line arguments.
2. You could provide some instructions to the user on termination of this application.

consider:

```
@Component
public class MyBean implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("App started with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

Details on [ApplicationRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner)

Answer (score 2):

ApplicationRunner and CommandLineRunner are two interfaces Spring Boot provides to run any custom code just before application is fully started.

Spring-batch is a batch processing framework. This uses CommandLineRunner to register and start batch jobs at application startup.

You can also use this interface to load some master data into cache/perform health checks.

The use-case varies from application to application.