# SpringBoot Active Profile in main method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

How can we get spring active profile programmatically in the main method before `SpringApplication.run()` method?

I have tried autowiring Environment Class and @Value annotation but both of them doesn't work out for main method.

Comment: Hmmm ... it probably in the bootstrap part of the process, which happens before the main container loads ... probably a different way of accessing it?

Comment: @JamesGawron may be ... that's what we need to figure out

Comment: I don't think you can. But what is it that you can do only in a main method that cannot be done anywhere else? Would an ApplicationRunner or a CommandLineRunner help?

Comment: I want to set an system property based on the profile before the application starts.

Comment: ApplicationRunner can do that for you. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328583/when-and-why-do-we-need-applicationrunner-and-runner-interface)

Comment: ApplicationRunner will be fired after the SpringApplication runs. So, it will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Programmatic approach:*

```
org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
String activeProfile = props.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
```

Comment: Apparently, this is the only way to do that.

Answer (score -3):

In the application.properties specify which profile to be active.
eg: spring.profiles.active = test

Comment: This would set the spring active profile, but does not show how the active profile can be accessed in the main method.